# Question about distribution of primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, logarithms

The following is from "Introduction to Number Theory" by Hardy and Wright.
The book first states the following theorem

> **Theorem A:** If $\pi(x)$ is number of primes not exceeding $x$ then $\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log{x}}$.

where $\sim$ stands for asymptotically similar. The book then states that the inverse of the function $\frac{x}{\log x}$ is asymptotic to the function $x \log {x}$ and thus **Theorem A** gives the following theorem

> **Theorem B:** $p_n \sim n\log{n}$.

where $p_n$ is the $n^{th}$ prime number. I am unable to understand how we get **Theorem B** from **Theorem A** ? Am I missing something trivial ?

Comment: You're asking for $\pi(x)=n$, then $x\sim n\log x \sim n\log n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of the prime counting function we have $\pi(p_n)=n$ for the $n$-th prime $p_n$. So, for $n\to \infty$,
$$
n=\pi(p_n)\sim \frac{p_n}{\log(p_n)},
$$
which says $p_n\sim n\log(n)$.

Comment: This just conclude that $p_{n} \sim n\ln p_{n} \implies p_{n}\sim -n W(-\frac{1}{n})$ only.

Comment: Also, $\pi(x)=n$ for $p_{n}\leq x<p_{n+1}$.  So $\frac{p_{n}}{\ln p_{n}} \lesssim n \lesssim \frac{p_{n+1}}{\ln p_{n+1}}$